# When I'm using header element and aurelia router-view together, the rendering of the header delays

Tags: javascript, aurelia

```
<template>
    <candidate-header id.bind="id"></candidate-header>
    <router-view></router-view>    
</template>
```

In the above code, the router-view component renders first and then the header renders after some time.

Comment: The code you mentioned is not complete enough to reproduce the problem. Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because as of right now, your code works fine. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidelines on how to ask a good question.

Comment: its probbly related to what's actually written inside the `candidate-header` component. maybe you are waiting for the `id` to bind to kick things off?